# Google Recaptcha not working on ui bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Here's my `HTML`:

I added `comments` on my HTML where I added the captcha element.

```html
<html>

<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>


</head>

<body ng-app="testApp">
    
    <!-- this will display -->
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lff8CETAAAAAA6CU-8CQYEzfQq7vXIxUmvyRR0w"></div>
    
    <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="ModalView.html">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h1> Captcha here!</h1>
                
                <!-- this will not display -->
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lff8CETAAAAAA6CU-8CQYEzfQq7vXIxUmvyRR0w"></div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
                <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </script>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="triggerModal()">Trigger Modal</button>

    </div>

</body>


</html>
```

And here's my `AngularJS` code:

```js
angular.module('testApp', ['ngAnimate','ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('testApp').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log) {
    
    
  $scope.triggerModal = function(){
      $scope.open();
  }


  $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'ModalView.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };

  $scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
    $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
  };

});

// Please note that $uibModalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.

angular.module('testApp').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

Comment: You would need to manually initialize it in a directive. Wouldn't be surprised  a module isn't already available for this

Comment: @charlietfl Right now, I'm trying to add it in the directive using `templateURL`. Some elements in my template showed up but the captcha won't show up. I'm still trying to figure it out though.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this is how I was able to show `google recaptcha` in my modal.

Here's my `index.html`

```html
<html>

<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body ng-app="testApp">
    
    <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="ModalView.html">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- Insert captcha here -->
                <my-template></my-template>                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
                <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </script>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="triggerModal()">Trigger Modal</button>

    </div>

</body>


</html>
```

Then, here's my `angular` code:

```js
angular.module('testApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('testApp').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log) {


    $scope.triggerModal = function () {
        $scope.open();
    }


    $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

    $scope.open = function (size) {

        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: $scope.animationsEnabled
            , templateUrl: 'ModalView.html'
            , controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {}, function () {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };

    $scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
        $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
    };

})

.directive('myTemplate', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var s = document.createElement('script');
            s.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js';
            document.body.appendChild(s);
        },
        template: '<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lff8CETAAAAAA6CU-8CQYEzfQq7vXIxUmvyRR0w"></div>'
    };
});

// Please note that $uibModalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.

angular.module('testApp').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {

    $scope.ok = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```